# Redis & Spring Boot integration with K8S error

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, redis

I have the following docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ENV PORT 8094
EXPOSE 8094
RUN mkdir -p /app/
COPY build/libs/fqdn-cache-service.jar /app/fqdn-cache-service.jar
WORKDIR /build
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh" "-c", "java -jar /app/fqdn-cache-service.jar" ]
```

docker-compose.yaml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: fqdn-cache-service
    ports:
      - "8094:8094"
    links:
      - "db:redis"
  db:
    image: "redis:alpine"
    #hostname: redis
    ports:
      - "6378:6378"
```

deployment.yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: fqdn-cache-service
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: spike
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
        run: spike
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: fqdn-cache-service
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          image: fqdn-cache-service:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8094
              protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: spike
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: spike
    spec:
      hostname: redis
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis:alpine
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fqdn-cache-service
  labels:
    run: spike
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 8094
      nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    run: spike
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    run: spike
    app: redis
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      nodePort: 30002
  selector:
    run: spike
```

And the cluster info ip is 127.0.0.1.
I'm using microk8s over ubuntu OS.
If I request for get by and ID (127.0.0.1/webapi/users/1) I get the error:

```
Cannot get Jedis connection; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
```

Although on regular java application with redis or dockerize spring boot with redis it's working.

Any help why this is happened?

This is the configuration of the spring boot:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        JedisConnectionFactory factory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
        factory.setPort(30001);
        factory.setUsePool(true);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    RedisTemplate redisTemplate() {
        RedisTemplate<String, FqdnMapping> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, FqdnMapping>();
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
        return redisTemplate;
    }
}
```

The issue also happenes if the host name is localhost and\or the port is 6379...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're running in a container, 127.0.0.1 usually refers to the container itself, not to the host the container is running on. If you're trying to connect to a service, try using its name and port: "redis" on port 6379 and "fqdn-cache-service" on 8094.

Comment: Thanks @Burak,
Also when host is redis and fqdn-cache-service, still don't work.
Also If I navigate in browser to fqdn-cache-service:8094 nothing happens.

Comment: Those names are valid only within a k8s cluster, not outside the cluster, so don't expect them to work when loaded with a browser. The point of a k8s service is to be able to locate these services using their DNS names, so name access should work between containers. I've never worked with microk8s though, does it have DNS support? If it does not, then my suggestion won't work.

Comment: Thanks! I had to enable DNS with `microk8s.enable dashboard dns`.
And host now is `redis` with port `6379`